# MessageBox in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: .net-core, messagebox

Microsoft documentation for .Net Core 3.1 says there is a MessageBox Class. If so, what is the NuGet package I need to download?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.messagebox?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: It's included in the dotnet core starting 3.1. Just make sure your project targets that version, and then in your project reference setting make sure you uses System.Windows

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I spent an hour researching this topic, tried various things from System.Windows.MessageBox.Show() to just plain MessageBox.Show() and nothing worked. You replied and now it works as expected....I am chasing ghosts!

Comment: I see I was not actually chasing ghosts. MessageBox.Show() does indeed appear in a .Net Core 3.1 Windows Application and works there BUT I was also trying to use it in a .Net Core 3.1 Class Library which is where it does not appear. Hence, question persists: can I use MessageBox in a class library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for me was to create a project in the solution using .Net framework. Specifically a Project/Class called NetFrame/Bridge. Then my .Net core projects in the solutions can call the .Framework project's one line method for MessageBox.

I am happy to report than having moved 250k lines of code from .Net Framework to .Net Core MessageBox is the ONLY method I had to add to the Bridge class!

Comment: This is curious. If your .net core 3.1 class library references another project which in turn references Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WPF then your class library can use MessageBox directly!

Comment: Net core 3.1 projects can references  .Net framework project ?

Comment: Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WPF nuget ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you would want a Windows message box 'showing' in your class library; surely your other UI projects which rely on your class library, would be the place where any dialog boxes need to be shown in the UI?

Comment: You are generally correct but I develop a lot of utilities and if I catch an error during coding I do not want to have to look in a log, for example, I want something in my face saying 'fix me'. It is not intended for end-user presentation.